# How to fade between two HTML fragments in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, settimeout

http://jsfiddle.net/SVtJV/16/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#footer-address").fadeOut(400);
        }, 2000);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#footer-address").fadeIn(400).html("<strong>Our Place</strong>  New Address Location");
        }, 2400);
        i++;
    }
});
```

I'm trying to get a block of code with `setTimeout` functions to run like 3 or 4 times with a for loop. Logically, I can see how my code within the for loop wouldn't want to repeat itself, probably because the `setTimeout` time values have already elapsed.

Is there a way to reset the time values before looping? Or is there a better way to execute the end goal?

Comment: 2 things I see... You're incrementing `i` twice, and you're not returning `$('#footer-address').html()` to its original state at any point.

Answer (score 2):

Each for-loop does not wait for the timeout to be finished, the whole for loop is done within 20 ms probably :D if you want to repeat the fades, you have to do a little function with callbacks.

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    var repeats = 4,
        times = 0,
        fade = function() {
            if (times >= repeats) return false;
            times++;
            $('#footer-address').fadeTo(400, 0, function() {
                $('#footer-address').html('text 1');
                $('#footer-address').fadeTo(400, 1, function() {
                    setTimeout(fade, 1000);
                });
            }); 
        };

    setTimeout(fade, 1000);
});
```

And I dont quite get what you are trying to do with the .html() there. Shall that change repeatedly?

Edited.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just trying to get "We've Moved..." to alternate with "New Address." The .html() was meant to insert new text into the #footer-address id.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the cleanest solution

[See it here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SVtJV/19/)

```
$(function() {
    var times = 3,
        elem = $('#footer-address')
        fader = setInterval(function() {
            elem.fadeOut(400, function() {
                elem.fadeIn(400);
            });
            if (--times === 0) {
                clearInterval(fader);
            }
        }, 1200);
});
```

Tweak the timing numbers until you're happy with the result.

Comment: But how do I get the element to alternate between "We have moved..." to the "new address"?

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you are incrementing `i` in two places (in the `for` afterthought and in the body of the loop), so removing the body assignment is the first part to fix. Also, the original HTML is not being "put back".

However, this is not the main problem. JavaScript is executing the loop (twice) instantly, so **all** the fadeOut/fadeIn functions execute after 2000/2400 milliseconds respectively, rather than being executed after a timeout as expected. You can check this by putting a `console.log(i);` or `alert(i);` in place of the `i++` in your demo and seeing 3 log lines/alerts as soon as the page has loaded.

I would put the markup as HTML, rather than creating it in JavaScript and then fade between the 2 HTML fragments, for example see [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pQrBG/) or following example code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer-address">
    <span><strong>We have moved!</strong> Our new address is:</span>
    <span><strong>Our Place</strong>  New Address Location</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer-address {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
}

#footer-address span:last-child {
    display:none;
}
```

**JavaScript** (requires jQuery)

```
var $footer = $('#footer-address');
var i = 0;

(function swap(){
    var $hiddenSpan = $footer.find('span:hidden')

    $footer.find('span:visible').fadeOut(400, function() {
        $hiddenSpan.fadeIn(400)
    })

    if (i++ < 3) setTimeout(swap, 2000)
})();
```

The JavaScript uses a self executing function (see http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/) that runs 3 times at 2 second intervals. I also utilise the *callback* (second) parameter of the jQuery [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) function so that the `.fadeIn()` is started *after* the fadeOut has finished.

I'm sure there's room for improvement here but hope it's useful nonetheless.

Comment: Hmmmm, implementation looks great in the fiddle demo but not so well on my site. Here's my site code:

Comment: 'code'
<style>
#footer-address span:last-child {
    display:none;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
var $footer = $('#footer-address');
var i = 0;

(function swap() {
    var $hiddenSpan = $footer.find('span:hidden');

    $footer.find('span:visible').fadeOut(400, function () {
        $hiddenSpan.fadeIn(400);
    });

    if (i++ < 4) setTimeout(swap, 2000);
})();
</script> 


 <div id="footer-address">
  <span><strong>We moved</strong></span>
                <span><strong>New Address</strong></span>
</div>'code'

Comment: Basically the <span> is hidden but the swap doesn't occur.

Comment: I think it is because in the fiddle, I am using the "onDomReady" selection (see the drop down top left) which wraps all the jQuery inside the _document ready_ function `$(function(){ });`. If you _View Source_ of the demo iFrame you will see it. I think your site is not functioning correctly as the browser's JavaScript engine is attempting to use jQuery functions without jQuery being loaded. The _document ready_ will delay the execution until the page and all resources (including scripts) have been fully loaded.

Comment: Good advice but still my site won't cooperate. Does it make a difference that I've got the call to 1.9.1.js code in a Drupal 6.28 footer block along with the rest of the code and not in the <head> tags? Or is running 1.3.2 and jQuery UI 1.7 the problem? 

I appreciate your help.

Comment: It will not make any difference where your `<script>` block is, as long as you include the jQuery library as well. It also works just fine with jQuery v1.3.2 - [**see demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pQrBG/9/). You don't need jQueryUI for this. However there might be a JavaScript error for another reason that is causing a problem. Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: I'm glad you asked. Check out two errors from the console:
'code'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; (program):587
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
 } has no method 'cookie'

Comment: So it looks like you have some code that is incorrectly calling `.cookie` on an object or possibly that you have some problems with jQuery plugins conflicting. Either way, it is causing other JavaScript on the page to not work. You need to track down the error on the page and fix that before the code in my answer will work on your page.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I suspect it's a conflict with our views cycle module because the content there disappears when I try to run the code.